# Postgres Copy data from two file in two table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to execute the `\copy` command to insert data to two tables from two files (The relations about then are master, details), to insert into the second one I need the id from the first one, I have a sequence to get the currvalue and call it with the nextval.

Master table

> Column          |            Type               id
>   | bigint                      | not null default
>   nextval('sclaims.claim_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
>   inserted_at             | timestamp without time zone   updated_at
>   | timestamp without time zone   authnum                 | character
>   varying(20)

Detail Table

> Column    |         Type          | Modifiers | 
>   master_id | bigint                | not null
>   ccid      | integer

Master Example File: 
559387  \N  \N  \N  984410  B1  1033349345

> 2016-12-31  28711123116BB               \N  1937-02-21  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N
>   559388    \N  \N  \N  984410  B1  1033349345      2016-12-31  28711123116BB
>         \N  1937-02-21  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N 559389   \N  \N  \N  984410  B1  1033349345      2016-12-31  28711123116BB
>         \N  1937-02-21  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N

Detail Example:

> 560097|1024|D5|405|030|||1|0 560097|1023|D3|403|02|||1|0
>   560097|1022|E7|442|60000|||1|0

Comment: please provide table structure and data samples from tose two files

Comment: Master table description
Column          |            Type              id                      | bigint                      | not null default nextval('sclaims.claim_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 inserted_at             | timestamp without time zone 
 updated_at              | timestamp without time zone

Comment: Detail table description
 Column    |         Type          | Modifiers | 
-------------+-----------------------+-----------
 claim_id    | bigint                | not null  
 ccid        | integer               |           
 field_id    | character varying(2)  |

Comment: the claim_id from the second is the pk from the first and in the copy statement i want to specify the currval from the sequence and when i import the master i am use the nextval.

Comment: noe please put that all to the questions from comments and give files samples?..

Comment: i saw at postgress documentation, that copy can't copy on multiple tables from one file.